How to merge two webm videos using Webcodecs API?
Multiple small video files are played like a single video in video tag using mediasource buffer. I would like to create them as a single video file if export option is desired. For that I would like to use WebCodecs API. Help is appreciated.
Tried much but getting different errors in different browsers. (like "encoder is undefined" in firefox, "Failed to execute 'decode' on 'VideoDecoder': A key frame is required after configure() or flush()." in chrome.
async function fetchVideoData(videoUrl) {
  const response = await fetch(videoUrl);
  if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to fetch video: ${response.statusText}`);
  }
  return response.arrayBuffer();
}

async function mergeWebMVideos(videoUrls) {
  const encodedChunks = [];
  let encoder;

  const initEncoder = (width, height) => {
      encoder = new VideoEncoder({
          output: (chunk) => {
              encodedChunks.push(chunk);
          },
          error: (e) => {
              console.error('Encoder error:', e);
          }
      });

      const config = {
          codec: 'vp8',
          width: width,
          height: height,
          bitrate: 4_000_000,
      };
      encoder.configure(config);
  };

  for (const videoUrl of videoUrls) {
      const videoData = await fetchVideoData(videoUrl);

      const decoder = new VideoDecoder({
          output: (frame) => {
              if (!encoder) {
                  initEncoder(frame.codedWidth, frame.codedHeight);
              } else {
                  if (frame.codedWidth !== encoder.width || frame.codedHeight !== encoder.height) {
                      encoder.configure({
                          codec: 'vp8',
                          width: frame.codedWidth,
                          height: frame.codedHeight,
                          bitrate: 4_000_000,
                      });
                  }
              }

              encoder.encode(frame);
              frame.close();
          },
          error: (e) => {
              console.error('Decoder error:', e);
          }
      });

      const stream = new ReadableStream({
          start(controller) {
              controller.enqueue(new Uint8Array(videoData));
              controller.close();
          }
      });

      const reader = stream.getReader();
        
      while (true) {
            const { done, value } = await reader.read();
            if (done) break;
            decoder.configure({
              codec: 'vp8'
            });
            const encodedChunk = new EncodedVideoChunk({
                type: 'key',
                timestamp: 0,
                byteLength: value.byteLength,
                data: value
            });
            decoder.decode(encodedChunk);
        }

        decoder.close();
  }

  encoder.close();

  const mergedVideoBlob = new Blob(encodedChunks, { type: 'video/webm' });

  return mergedVideoBlob;
}


(1) Can you provide 2 test files to test your code with? Otherwise it's not clear why the browsers are giving errors about the input. (2) If the videos are same type (same resolution, FPS, etc) then I would forget webCodecs and try to do this via bytes editing. Usually you edit the header of the first file (change its duration to include time of other segments), then on the other files you remove (or skip) their own header and join their "a/v frames" section into the first file. You need to investigate WebM file structure and practice file editing with a Hex editor, before writing code...
